# Android onCreate of Activity class is not triggered

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am trying to write a plugin for Capacitor. It should pass the accelerometer data to the JavaScript. The bridge works fine.
However, the heading class does not seem to be initialized. The onCreate function does not seem to be executed, so do all the other functions. Nothing is logged to the console.
In AndroidManifest.xml I have requested the following feature:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

The file looks like this:

```
package de.example.capmap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

import de.example.Compass;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    private Heading heading;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        registerPlugin(Compass.class);
        heading = new Heading();
    }

}

class Heading extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    private static final String TAG = "Heading";

    @Override
    public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Initializing");

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(Heading.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
        Log.i(TAG, "onSensorChanged: " +  event.values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged:" +  accuracy);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

and the Compass Plugin, which gets executed:

```
import com.getcapacitor.JSObject;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod;
import com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin;
import com.getcapacitor.Bridge;


@CapacitorPlugin(name = "Compass")
public class Compass extends Plugin  {

    public static Bridge staticBridge = null;

    @Override
    public void load() {
        staticBridge = this.bridge;
        java.lang.System.out.println("Compass successfully started");
    }

    public static void onMagneticHeading(float magneticHeading){
        Compass pushPlugin = Compass.getCompassInstance();
        if (pushPlugin != null) {
            pushPlugin.sendMagneticHeading(magneticHeading);
        }
    }

    @PluginMethod()
    public void getMagneticHeading(PluginCall call) {
        String value = call.getString("value");
        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        ret.put("magneticHeading", value);
        call.resolve(ret);
    }

    public void sendMagneticHeading(float magneticHeading) {
        JSObject data = new JSObject();
        data.put("magneticHeading", magneticHeading);
        notifyListeners("heading", data, true);
    }


    public static Compass getCompassInstance() {
        if (staticBridge != null && staticBridge.getWebView() != null) {
            PluginHandle handle = staticBridge.getPlugin("Compass");
            if (handle == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (Compass) handle.getInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should **never** create an activity yourself with `new SomeActivity();`, it will not work properly. If Heading is not supposed to be an activity, it should not extend AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

How come you're extending an `Activity` instead of just using a plain class? If it's because you want access to a `Context`, just pass one in through the constructor (you have one when you create the `Heading`).

If it's because you want the `onPause` and `onResume` lifecycle callbacks, so you know when to register/unregister with the `SensorManager`, there's a couple of things you could do.

First you can just create some methods the activity can call during `onPause`/`onResume`:

```
class Heading(Context context) {
    
    ...

    public void sleep() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void wake() {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

}

class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        heading.wake();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        heading.sleep();
    }
}
```

The other approach is to make `Heading` implement `DefaultLifecycleObserver`, which basically lets you implement `onResume` and `onPause` etc like you're doing, and you make it *observe* the Activity's lifecycle, instead of the Activity having to manually call stuff to be like "hey `onPause` just happened". [I'll just link the example page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc), but it basically covers what you're doing here (and the earlier, manual example too) as well as some more advanced stuff